# Meaning of enum values starting at 0x0007

Tags: enums

I'm looking through the header files of a library I'm using (I don't have the implementation source files), and I noticed that there is a set of enums that proceed like so (simplified):

```
enum Type
{
    Type1                   = 0x0007,   
    Type2                   = 0x000A,  
    Type3                   = 0x000B,    
    Type4                   = 0x000C,    
    Type5                   = 0x000D,   
    Type6                   = 0x000E, 
    Type7                   = 0x000F, 
    Type8                   = 0x0010,  
};
```

I'm familiar with seeing a 1,2,4,8... progression for using the enums as bit flags, but is this 7,10,11... any kind of standard pattern? I know there's not necessarily much meaning to the values, but this seemed oddly specific since most of the values are sequential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't unusual to see a progression with missing numbers. They might be used internally by the library, used by some other external component with which the library interfaces, or reserved for future development.

To be safe, only use the defined values.

Comment: Your answer made me think: The particular enum that was 7 is used as a signed 64 bit integer (according to an attached comment). I'm sure it's no coincidence that there are 6 pairs of integral types smaller than it (8,16,32 but signed and unsigned), then presumably an unsigned 64 bit, then a pair of 128 bits, then double and so on. These types are passed as arguments to dll functions. Future proofing? Legacy code? Either way the pattern doesn't seem as arbitrary now!